# Node list is empty: button is glyphicon

Tags: php, symfony, domcrawler

A functional test with `$form = $crawler->selectButton('input[type=submit]')->form();` fails with

> The current node list is empty

Source code:

```
<form action="/household/_search" class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="qtext" method="get" class="form-control" placeholder="Full name or ID">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
</form>
```

The result is the same with:

- `selectButton('.btn')`
- `filterXPath('span[@class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"]')`
- `filter('navbar-form')`
- `filter('.btn')`
- `filter('input[type="submit"]')`
- `filter('input[type=submit]')`

What is the correct selector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see on the documentation, to get a form in the crawler, it should match the id or name for buttons.

Assume your button has an id="submit-form" then your form in test should :

```
$crawler->selectButton('submit-form')->form();
```

Check [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/testing.html#forms) for the doc. Hope it will help

Comment: This is close enough.  The eventual solution required clearing the test cache and modifying the source code to fit the test.  The form tag was modified to include `id="household_search"` and the test was modified to `$form = $crawler->filter('#household_search')->form();`

Comment: Oh yeah almost there :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have an input of the type submit, you have a button with the type submit.

```
$form = $crawler->selectButton('button[type=submit]')->form();
```

Comment: This unfortunately also results in `node list is empty`.  That and `button[type="submit"]`.